# How to decrease edge loops in skin modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry

Hi so I'm using the skin modifier to extrude some vertices and it works relatively well except that it too much geometry/too many edge loops and there's too many for me to go back and remove manually. Is there a way to fix this?
[image]

with decimator modifier:
[image]

Comment: "masking" isn't the best choice of tags to get more help or answers.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to put "skin" in the tags but it doesn't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it

Answer (score 1):

If you add the Decimate Modifier next to appear under Skin, I see no reason "Planar" won't satisfy you even at a default Angle Limit of 5-degrees. With Wireframe enabled in (Object Properties) Viewport Display, you can see the results immediately in Object Mode and change the Angle Limit as needed.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I added the decimate modifier and planar and it didn't change anything and neither did changing the angle I updated the image in the post

Comment: Try shift + Click "Regular" in the skin modifier to unselect it. In my version (2.81) it is called "normal" which can indeed be translated to "regular" but in the realm of 3D modelling doesn't mean the same thing at all

Comment: You'll see the potential changes in Object Mode, not Edit Mode. But you ARE doing it right :)

Comment: @Gorgious I hadn't know that about the Shift+Click to deselect. It was freaking me out a little that I couldn't reset those options to null. tx

Comment: @Gorgious Yeah I did that and it didn't change anything. Not sure what now. I even applied the skin modifier then the decimate and that didn't have any effect either, the excessive geometry is still there.